# In pandas dataframe, Need to split columns and add them back to other rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `STATUS` column in data frame which I am getting the counts using `value_count` function

```
df.STATUS.value_counts(sort=True)
```

Output:

```
Verified               171
ErrTab;                  9
WarKeyWord;              4
ErrTab; and WarKeyWord; 10
```

so now I want to break the last row and add the values to previous counts.

Expected:

```
Verified        171
ErrTab;          19
WarKeyWord;      14
```

What would be the easiest way to do this? any ideas?

Comment: `df.STATUS.str.split(" and ").explode().value_counts()` ?

Comment: Maybe `df.STATUS.str.replace(' and ', '').str.split(';').explode().value_counts()`.

Comment: @QuangHong, that's perfect but now in results I have an additional empty column value with count. 
`Verified      172
               13
ErrTab          9
WarKeyWord      4`

count 13 has now column value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get not too long source DataFrame, I defined it
as:

```
                     STATUS  Amount
0                  Verified       1
1                  Verified       2
2                  Verified       3
3                   ErrTab;       1
4                   ErrTab;       2
5                   ErrTab;       3
6                   ErrTab;       4
7                   ErrTab;       5
8                   ErrTab;       6
9                   ErrTab;       7
10                  ErrTab;       8
11                  ErrTab;       9
12              WarKeyWord;       1
13              WarKeyWord;       2
14              WarKeyWord;       3
15              WarKeyWord;       4
16  ErrTab; and WarKeyWord;       1
17  ErrTab; and WarKeyWord;       2
18  ErrTab; and WarKeyWord;       3
```

(3, 9, 4 and 3 items with each *STATUS*).

Then, to get your expected result, run:

```
df.STATUS.str.split(' and ').explode().value_counts(sort=True)
```

The result is:

```
ErrTab;        12
WarKeyWord;     7
Verified        3
Name: STATUS, dtype: int64
```

Due to the different number of occurrences of each *STATUS*,
the result ordering is different (a side effect of my source data).